# How to add a default image in the dropzone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/8cy20hhL/5/)

What I want to do is that when the page loads, there was already a charged image

**CODE JS:**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", {
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    maxFiles:1,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function() {
        this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
            this.removeFile(file);
            alert("No more files please!");
        });
    },
    url: "#"
});
```

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myDrop">
                                 <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="">
                                      <span>Drag and upload your profile photo</span>
                                 </div>
                        </div>
```

Is there any possibility to load a picture from the first? Without the added user

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you want to load a picture first? Or where do you want to show a picture? Which added user do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", {
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    maxFiles:1,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function() {

            var thisDropzone = this;
            var mockFile = { name: 'Name Image', size: 12345, type: 'image/jpeg' };
            thisDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
            thisDropzone.emit("success", mockFile);
            thisDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "https://example.com")

            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
            this.removeFile(file);
            alert("No more files please!");
            });

          }, 
    url :  " # " 
});
```

Comment: I also added thisDropzone.emit("complete",mockFile);